# Unwanted Line when Using R's Pairs Function

Tags: r, compilation, correlation

I have an unwanted line when I use R's `pairs` function.

Here is my code:

```
dfcomp = df[,c(4,6,7)]
pairs(dfcomp, cex = 2, main = "", pch = 1, 
   labels = c("Mean", "Maximum", "Variance"), col = "blue", las = 1)
minor.tick(0,4)
```

And here is my output:[image]

I do not know why the line on the left cutting through the boxes is appearing, and I would like to get rid of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try your code without `minor.tick(0,4)`, it is explicitly adding ticks (and the axis).

Comment: That's it, thanks!